# sql concatenation

Tags: php, sql

Can I concatenate queries like below? If no, how should I proceed? I don't want to read rows from `$retrieveUnitExist` as it waste another step.

```
$retrieveUnitExist = "SELECT unitid FROM ESTATEUNIT WHERE BLOCK = 1";
$insertAddress = "INSERT INTO ADDRESS (value1, value2) VALUES ('1','".$retrieveUnitExist."')";

mysqli_query($conn, $insertAddress);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$insertAddress = "INSERT INTO ADDRESS (value1, value2)
                  SELECT '1', unitid FROM ESTATEUNIT WHERE BLOCK = 1";
```

Comment: May I know why select '1' is included? It should be seperated from the query unitid FROM ESTATEUNIT WHERE BLOCK = 1";

Comment: @Bryan Wong he's using the select statement to do the insert instead of a hard coded `values()` statement

Comment: @BryanWong `SELECT '1'` is included as the value from your `INSERT`.